# notification to another view

Tags: objective-c, ios7, notifications, xcode5

i try to think that someone but without succes.
    Any id

```
// MasterViewController
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:myParametersArray forKey:@"myParametersArray"]; // add 'string' as object with key name is also 'myArrayKey'
[userDefaults synchronize];

// Another View.
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

myParametersArray  = [defaults objectForKey:@"myParametersArray"];
myParametersArray[STR_OPTION_PSEUDO] = [NSNumber  numberWithInteger:_RetainPseudoSwitch.enabled];
```

info myParametersArray is NSMutableArray

reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

In MasterViewController no problem, i can store an object to my array.
In Second view i receive this see above

Comment: reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please always include the error message and other details (if available) directly in your questions!

Comment: NSMutableArray *myParametersArray

Comment: You can edit your question so other users dont have to read through all the comments

Comment: Be careful, some reviewers are very picky about what data you store and where.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're using this way for posting notifications, but I'll try to help you.

This line will assign NSArray object to your myParametersArray variable and will change its type to NSArray. You can't mutate a NSArray object.

```
myParametersArray  = [defaults objectForKey:@"myParametersArray"];
```

Replace it with this:

```
myParametersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"myParametersArray"]];
```

Also, you should set array objects like this:

```
[myParametersArray setObject:[NSNumber  numberWithInteger:_RetainPseudoSwitch.enabled] atIndex:[STR_OPTION_PSEUDO]];
```

Comment: In fact i need for all views my option parameters and in my head i created in my MasterViewController a mutable array.

Comment: So in second view i retrieve my array and i would try this solution for views can put object to my master view

Comment: [myParametersArray setObject:[NSNumber  numberWithInteger:_RetainPseudoSwitch.enabled] atIndexedSubscript:(STR_OPTION_PSEUDO)];